# Count up Timer changes for text output

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

I'm a real JS novice. I finally found a simple webpage-only script that gives a count up time from a fixed date, and with beginner's luck I tweaked it to give text output in minutes and hours from the supplied span html.

However it shows "Updated 0 hours 9 min ago".

I want to remove the unnecessary '0 hours' until 60 minutes have passed to show: "Updated 9 min ago".

Then show hours again: "Updated 1 hours 1 min ago".

Appreciate any help on this, many thanks.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("Jan 22, 2020 08:45:30", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};
function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
      countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
      timeDifference = (now - countFrom);

  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
      secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function(){ countUpFromTime(countFrom, id); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: you can use an `if` statement to control the display of the 'hours' class. Something like: `if (hours == 0) { idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden'; }` or use `.style.display = 'none'` to hide the hours when there are none

Comment: Great, we're nearly there. It is now "updated hours 3 min ago". It got rid of the 0 but not the hour.

Comment: OK, it was a shot in the dark as you hadn't provided any HTML. Is the "hours" part inside an HTML tag of some sort? Can you share that part of the code?

Comment: Here's the part of the webpage HTML where it references hours if that helps:
`<div class="countup" id="countup1">` 
`<span class="timeel hours">00</span>`  `<span class="timeel timeRefHours">hours</span>`

Comment: The class for the span tag that shows the word "hours" is "timeRefHours", so you could include `idEl.getElementsByClassName('timeRefHours')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';` inside that `if` condition to hide that as well. You shouldn't need to worry about extra spaces as whitespace in markup only gets counted the first time

Comment: Great, thanks - that worked. I've spent hours researching this. I should have come here earlier!